# PowerShell and SQL server

Tags: sql, powershell

Currently I'm working on a PowerShell script which is extracting info about OS, hotfix and installed software.

Well, everything is working well if I want to export to txt file - everything.

But my new task is to upload this information to sql server.

So I'm creating a foreach loop to print installed software and put everything in server. PowerShell isn't showing any errors but I can't get this data into sql server.

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=myserver; Initial Catalog=table; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$conn.Open()
$soft = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$cmd.Connection = $conn
$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
foreach ($Software in $soft){

$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (SoftName, SoftVersion) VALUES ('$($Software.Name)', $($Software.Version))" }

$cmd.CommandText = $query
$result = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
$conn.close()
```

So the idea is that when I run this script, I get all software installed on pc listed in sql server.

SoftName:      SoftVersion:

Office           14.202

Sql               15

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What do you get in $result variable when you run your script?
I believe, that you get signatures of overloaded methods with the name ExecuteNonQuery. The proper method call looks like this:

```
$result = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If you see errors I would recommend you to use code below to get full information about them:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$Error.Clear()
try {
    # Your code
}
catch {
    $Error | Format-List * -Force
}
```

Comment: Now Im getting error in powershell - Incorrect syntax near '.2100' and under that overloaddefinitions

Comment: That's not a PowerShell error, but an SQL error, I guess.

Comment: I've updated the post with ways how to get more information about errors. Can you post the results of running updated code?

Comment: Also, please post the value of the $query variable

Comment: Error code is too big, i copied it into txt file, here is a link - http://efshare.com/?s=WCELTH . About $query , Im getting exactly the same error.

Comment: What do you mean 'you get the same error'? Just type   Write-Host $query;   before you perform call ExecuteNonQuery. I guess the issue is in query syntax (probably in Software version value), but without the actual query It's hard to be sure)))

Comment: Here is a output in txt file - http://efshare.com/?s=J66LRK . Sorry, I misunderstand you. Im new in this whole powershell world. :)

Comment: What type you use to store value 12.0.6012.5000? The problem is definitely here. You can try to use String type, or you can perform transformations in SQL or PowerShell, like splitting version value to 4 columns and etc. Also, there are certain rules on this site that don't appreciate use comments as chat. If my answer is not sufficient you should ask you SQL guys your current problem you are facing.

Comment: I removed softversion checking to make sure if it is making these error. But nothing changed. For softname im using varchar but nothing changed. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I was talking about "SoftVersion" value

Comment: Varchar(1000) for it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the insert command instead of appending into it. In addition, as levgen points out, you are missing method call syntax:

```
foreach ($Software in $soft){
    $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (SoftName, SoftVersion) VALUES ('$($Software.Name)', $($Software.Version))" 
} # Oops!
# Now $query contains only the last insert statement.
$cmd.CommandText = $query
$result = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery # Should be .ExecuteNonQuery()
$conn.close()
```

Try something like so,

```
foreach ($Software in $soft){
    $query += "INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (SoftName, SoftVersion) VALUES ('$($Software.Name)', $($Software.Version));" 
} # Appending insert staements
# Now $query should contain lots of insert staements
$cmd.CommandText = $query
$result = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! Something new appeared. But now Im getting bunch of errors about incorrect syntax near and some numbers

Comment: @user22401 Add the errors into the post. Without specific error messages not much can be done.

Comment: Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near '.6012'.
Incorrect syntax near '.4763'.
Incorrect syntax near '.4763'.
Incorrect syntax near '.4763'.
Incorrect syntax near '.4763'.
Incorrect syntax near '.4763'.
Incorrect syntax near '.4763'.
Incorrect syntax near '.4763'.
Incorrect syntax near '.4763'.
Incorrect syntax near '.4763'.

Comment: There is much more of them but many of error codes are the same.